# How can I compress my c++ code in a single line?

Tags: javascript, c++, html, documentation

I am writing document with html and javascript.

I want to compress my c++ code into a single line(to save bytes), how can I do that efficiently?

Comment: I think you have to do it manually. Just my thinking. :)

Comment: If there are a lot of files to be processed, some script will do this for you. Just pick one scripting language (bash, python, perl) and write it. To save bytes, you can also remove all unnecessary white spaces (not that trivial job, but still something).

Comment: `Ctrl+H` (or `Ctrl+F`), check 'regular expression', replace `\n` with nothing, hit 'replace all', done.

Comment: If you don't mind the code being unreadable, you can obfuscate it down to one line. But a few line feeds in your source probably won't save you that many bytes and may cost you in maintenance far worse later on.

Comment: Removing 'newline characters' is a trivial enough task. But don't do this. You can use a compression algorithm (like a .zip file) simply enough. This will compress your human readable C++ source code into a blob of compressed data.

Comment: I agree with thecoshman. You won't save a lot by removing newline charaters. If you want it to be code and not compressed data, you should use an obfuscator that will rename all functions / variables to one-letters (or two-letters), and that will probably compress way more.

Comment: Yes... obfuscating the code can help the source file use less space, but it's a pointless endeavor. You only make the source code harder to work with, not impossible.

Comment: It is relevant when talking about javascript, where he can compress the webpage version and not the dev one. But for C++, it is not that useful.

Answer (score 2):

Sublime text editor does it directly just select the text and press 'ctrl+j'

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr there are your input in vim.
`g g 1 0 0 0 0 shift+j`

1. Open your files with VIM.
2. Go to the first line (gg).
3. The shorcut to do what you want is J (shift + j). So write 10000 J
   (to do it on 10 000 lines).

Comment: Depend on your environnement. Using VIM since 10 years to development and for me it's the fastest way.

Comment: My bad, didn't saw your edit. Even with that, I think it is faster with a proper IDE (it also handles multiple files), but yours can be valid.

Comment: @Synxis with huge files VIM is still much faster than any IDE.

Comment: @Synxis: What makes you think Vim can't run a command on several files in one shot ?

Comment: @Synxis `:bufdo %join` job done. `:argdo` to operate on all commandline arguments (see `:args`) instead

Comment: Usually I do massive change with `grep | sed` , but nice commands indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This is ridiculous. If you want compression, use a compression algorithm.

E.g. All lines with `#` should be skipped, line-continuation characters should be removed, for starters.

However, as a quick start:

```
:%j
```

will join all lines in the current buffer on a single line.

```
:args **/*.cpp
:silent! argdo %j
```

applies it to all cpp files in (subfolders of) the current directory.

Use autowrite (`:se aw`) to enable saving on the fly. Or just `:wa`